# Dark Mode React Class Component

Tags: reactjs

Well I'm trying to use dark and light mode on navbar using toggle switch but when I click on the switch it shows an error:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Below is the code using state and it is a class based component.

Help me out!

Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


export class Navbar extends Component {
    constructor()
  {
      super();
      this.state={
                  mode:"light"
      }
  }
   
    async toggle()
    {
        if(this.state.mode==="light")
        {
            this.setState(
                {
                    mode:"dark"
                }
            )
        }
        else{
            this.setState(
                {
                    mode:"light"
                }
            )
        }
    } 
    
  render() {
    
    return (
      
      <div>
          {console.log(this.state.mode)}
            <nav className={`navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-${this.state.mode} bg-${this.state.mode}`}>
  <div className="container-fluid">
    <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">EasyNews</Link>
    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link className="nav-link" aria-current="page" to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
       
         <li className="nav-item">
          <Link className="nav-link" to="/business">Business</Link>
          </li>
         <li className="nav-item">
          <Link className="nav-link" to="/entertainment">Entertainment</Link>
          </li>
         <li className="nav-item">
          <Link className="nav-link" to="/health">Health</Link>
          </li>
         <li className="nav-item">
          <Link className="nav-link" to="/science">Science</Link>
          </li>
         <li className="nav-item">
          <Link className="nav-link" to="/sports">Sports</Link>
          </li>
         <li className="nav-item">
          <Link className="nav-link" to="/technology">Technology</Link>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
          <Link className="nav-link" to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div className="form-check form-switch">
  <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" onClick={this.toggle} />
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: onClick ={this.toglle} has called with other `this` try add this.toggle=this.toggle.bind(this) in your constructor

Answer (score 1):

> By default `this` is not in the context of the component, so you have to `bind` the `this` value to `toggle` function

More About `bind` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
export class Navbar extends Component {
    constructor()
    {
            super();
            this.state = {
            mode:"light"
            }
            this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);// bind here
    }
   
    async toggle()
    {
        if(this.state.mode==="light")
        {
            this.setState(
                {
                    mode:"dark"
                }
            )
        }
        else{
            this.setState(
                {
                    mode:"light"
                }
            )
        }
    }
    render(
        ....
    )
```

Comment: Why you won't accept my answer? any reason